# toString method with subclasses

Tags: java, subclass, tostring, superclass

I am creating a program with many subclasses (A through G) and am trying to use the toString method to create a printable representation of an object reference from the subclass G.  Class G inherits from class F.  I'm not too familiar with toString yet and can't figure out how to do something like this.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return /* fill this in */;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `toString()` method from the superclass:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getCanonicalName();
}
```

The above will simply return the canonical name of the class

Answer (score 0):

Override the toString() method in the class G where you will have the access to the members of G and its parent classes till its root in the hierarchy. Prepare a string out of all the instance variables by concatenating with meaningful prefixes. example: "Age:"+ this.age+"Salary:"+this.salary; Hope this is helpful.